# MySQL Treating Varchar in SP as Hexadecimal

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, hex, varchar

I have a stored procedure with the following inputs:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AssignValuePosition
(
    IN accountId INT,
    IN valueType VARCHAR(128),
    IN value VARCHAR(2000)
)
```

If I call the SP like so it fails:

```
call AssignValuePosition( 15, 'URL', 'hyh00x1' );
```

I found the problem to be the last parameter, specifically the 0x1. If I call the SP with a value of:

```
call AssignValuePosition( 15, 'URL', 'hyh00x' );
```

It works fine. Anyone know why this is? How I can work around this?

Comment: Your problem is unclear. Provide complete (simplified) example which demonstrates your issue.

Comment: Show us the stored procedure?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue https://dbfiddle.uk/9PL1b3mL